# I am having error while writing a sql query in bigqquery

Tags: google-bigquery

> create or replace
> mythirdproject-345809.Test_dataset.Head_Of_country_cdc as select * ,
> current_timestamp as created_dt, current_timestamp as last_updated_dt,
> 'Initial Load' as last_updated_by, from
> mythirdproject-345809.Test_dataset.Head_Of_country;

I tried creating a table using sql query in bigquery but i am getting error

> (mythirdproject is not a supported object type at [1:19])

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you don't specify the type of object that you are trying to create. The correct [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) is `CREATE [OR REPLACE] TABLE <table_name>` so your query should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `mythirdproject-345809.Test_dataset.Head_Of_country_cdc` AS 
SELECT * , 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS created_dt, 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS last_updated_dt, 
'Initial Load' AS last_updated_by 
FROM `mythirdproject-345809.Test_dataset.Head_Of_country`;
```